# JAVA : Send an object to the server

Tags: java, object, client, server

I am a beginner in JAVA and I try to send an object from my client to my server.

The first object from  the client works, but when I run an another client,

the first object runs an exception to the server :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7372000F
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at ircproject.MainServer.main(MainServer.java:43)
```

Java Result: 1

I do not understand why.

This is my code :

Client :

```
public class MainClient {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket socket;
    Scanner ScanNick;
    String nick;

    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2009);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //Les données envoyées par le serveur
    String message_distant = in.readLine(); //Premier message envoyé du client
    System.out.println(message_distant);//On l'affiche

    System.out.println("Bonjour, quel est votre pseudo? ?");
    ScanNick = new Scanner(System.in);
    nick = ScanNick.nextLine();

    User user = new User(nick, false, false, true);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); //On prépare l'envoie du pseudo
    out.println(user.getNick()); //C'est le message qu'on veut envoyé
    out.flush();//On l'envoie

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(user);
```

Server :

```
public class MainServer extends Thread {

private static final boolean stop = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ServerSocket socketserver;
    Socket socketduserveur;
    socketserver = new ServerSocket(2009); //Création d'un serveur sur le port 2009

    while (!stop) {
        try {
            socketduserveur = socketserver.accept(); //On accepte les connexions
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socketduserveur.getOutputStream()); //Objet PrintWriter pour envoyé un message au serveur
            out.println("Coucou Client :)"); //Message dans l'objet PrintWriter qui va etre envoyé au client
            out.flush(); // Envoie du message

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketduserveur.getInputStream())); //On va lire une donnée envoyé par le serveur
            String nick = in.readLine(); //On stock le message dans la variable nick
            System.out.println(nick + " c'est connecté");

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socketduserveur.getInputStream());
            User u = (User)ois.readObject();

            u.addUserList(u.getNick());
            u.addUserList("john");

            if(u.listAlone()){
                System.out.println("Vous etes admin");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Would it be possible to post all the code for the server? You may need to make it a multi-threaded server if it is to serve multiple clients.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the entire stack trace? Is it the client or server throwing this exception?

Comment: You are using the same stream first as text reader and then as object input stream? Regardless of the clients, that's highly likely to corrupt.

Comment: It is the server which throws this exception. Sorry but I do not understand when you say "stack trace" :/ What is it ? Do you want the entire code for the client ?

Comment: Stack trace: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVM8F0omx1M)

Comment: The stack trace is the output that is displayed in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse) when your program crashes. It is a capture of the function calls leading up to the function that caused the crash. In your case, it shows "java.io.StreamCorruptedException" at the top.

Comment: Can you also add the two nicks that are sent by the client? It may help explain the corruption. The full user records may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have deleted my InputStream and it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you read a line on the server side and take that as the nickname, but you never send it to the server. Before you send the user object to the server, you need to send the nickname as a String. With minimal impact to the client code, the best way I can think of to do this is:

Client-side:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(nick + "\r\n");
oos.writeObject(user);
```

assuming `nick` is a String.

The reason the `StreamCorruptedException` is thrown is that after you have read a portion of the serialised `User` object and used that as the nickname, you instantiate an `ObjectInputStream` which immediately tries to read a serialised object header. As you have already read the object header, the next few bytes are invalid as a header so the ObjectInputStream complains.

**EDIT:** After you clarified that you are actually sending the nickname, your problem could be that you are retrieving the InputStream from the socket again (`getInputStream()`). Try getting the stream, reading from it with the BufferedReader and not closing the reader (because that will close the stream), then instantiating the ObjectInputStream *with the same InputStream* before reading your `User`.

Comment: Why should it be sent to the client? It's read from the client.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I didn't tell the OP to send the nick to the client, I told them to send it to the server (and it's read on the server on line 19).

Comment: Ah, well, "send it client-side" is ambiguous.

Comment: Ho sorry, it is because I have used bad name for my variable... I have edited my post with the client-side, it is more 
understandable :)

Comment: Thanks it is working, I have deleted my inputStream (It is just a test, I don't need InputStream) :)